# Trying to pull a cell with a Date from another google sheet, add text but getting the serial number instead of the date

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The value I want from another google sheet is

```
May 30, 2022
```

I want to add a text string to this
`" Time Sheet"`

I am using this:

```
='TimeSht 5/30 - 6/12'!K5&" Time Sheet"
```

I get this

```
44711 Time Sheet
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand the relationship between `The value I want from another google sheet is May 30, 2022`, `I want to add a text string to this " Time Sheet"`, `I am using this ='TimeSht 5/30 - 6/12'!K5&" Time Sheet"`, `I get this 44711 Time Sheet` and your tag of `google-sheets-api`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: Use `TEXT()` or `TO_TEXT()`

Comment: Sorry, new here. Maybe I tagged it incorrectly. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

### TEXT() is your friend

A date is technically a number formatted as a string. Use TEXT to make the illusion of a string into a reality.

```
=TEXT('TimeSht 5/30 - 6/12'!K5, "MMM dd, YYYY")&" Time Sheet"
```

Comment: Perfect - Thank you so much! So simple but I couldn't find the answer by searching the web. Perhaps I was asking the wrong question. Thanks again :)

Comment: You're welcome!  please select my answer as being the answer!